# Did I draw this phrase diagram correctly?

Tags: phrases, sentence

Hello beautiful people,

I am writing an exam on English grammar soon and one part is requiring you to draw a phrase diagram separating the noun phrases, verb phrases, etc..

Now I took a sentence from the first Harry Potter book (c) All rights reserved, and made it into a phrase tree.

Did I do everything correctly?

NP stands for noun phrase

VP for verb phrase

PP for prepositional phrase

[image: Clause tree]

All Feedback is appreciated!

Comment: related: [Need a bit of help with drawing parse trees](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267417/need-a-bit-of-help-with-drawing-parse-trees) and [Building a phrase structure of “On the weekend …”](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/93994/44619)

Comment: and [Can someone help me diagram this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21978/can-someone-help-me-diagram-this-sentence/22236#22236)

Answer (score 2):

I think you've diagrammed it as though Dursley is a director called Grunnings and that it's he who made drills personally. :-)

I'll let these step-by-step illustrations speak for themselves:

[image: successive levels of diagramming for the whole sentence]

Focusing on the portion of the sentence qualifying the word "director":

[image: successive levels of diagramming for "a firm called Grunnings which made drills"]

Alternatively, with the indefinite article, I think it can also be parsed this way, if we think of "Grunnings" as a unique identifier that, if applied first, would make "a" redundant, which it isn't:

[image: Alternate treatment for the firm]

I'll leave "called Grunnings" and "which made drills" as an exercise.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your awesome reply. At first I had to chuckle but now I am starting to understand. Here is also a very good graphic which helped me to understand https://imgur.com/a/ZVd7De6 . I will update you later on the correct graphic! :)

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, I don't think so. The basic structure is

NP---------------------VP

```
             V------------NP
```

Use a substitution test like *He was something.*

That's the top of the structure.

Then the subject complement is just

NP------------------PP

the dir.

```
           P------------NP

           of          
                Det-----------NP

                 a          firm

                              Reduced relative clause: [that was] called G.

                                                          Full relative clause:

                                                              NP----VP

                                                            which     V-----NP

                                                                     made  dills
```